# c# how to check if QueryString Values count has the same value as count of keys

Tags: c#, dictionary

Here is my problem:

If my url has QueryString `?asdasdafa` I can handle it with : `if(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.HasKeys())`

But if my url has QueryString `?asdasasfasdas&brand=Sony` then it will fail with null exception because is actually has one key, and the other one doesn't have it. Is there an easy way to check

```
if(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.KeysCount ==
HttpContext.Current.Request.QuesryString.ValuesCount))
```

Comment: In your second example, `asdasasfasdas&brand` is interpreted as the key. The pseudo-code will not help at all.

Comment: Yeah, so this key doesn't have a value, that's why it fails. If I could check if the number of values is equal to number of keys,  I think I'll be good.

Comment: But it does, in your example the value of `Request.QueryString["asdasasfasdas&brand"]` would be `Sony`. There would be no `brand` key, however.

Comment: WHo generating such a key? Perhaps it worth to fix it on generator side?

Comment: If a spider follows such a link, it was put somewhere. Check your site - you might have it somewhere by mistake.

Comment: it's something related with Facebook, it's like fb_akjg_oier or something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you need to do that, doing a simple null check will suffice

```
if(Request.QueryString["asdasdafa"]==null)
{
   // value missing
}
```

The fact that `asdasdafa` is not even included as one of the keys on the QueryString won't make your application throw an Exception.

**EDIT**

Based on the comment, you could then walk through the keys present as so:

```
foreach (var item in Request.QueryString.AllKeys)
{
   if (Request.QueryString[item] == null)
                //value missing

}
```

Comment: I don't know what the name of it is though. For some reason crawler is doing those weird keys.

Comment: @bobek: Check my edit. Will that suffice? You can write a little method to return `true` or `false` based on whether one value is missing or not

Answer (score 1):

When I run your 2nd example, `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.HasKeys()` doesn't fail for me, and `asdasasfasdas` is the first value I get, but its key is `null`. You can check if the key is null by

```
NameValueCollection nvc = Context.Request.QueryString;
if (nvc.GetKey(0) == null){}
```

Comment: That's not answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether HasKeys can handle that, If not,how about writing your own extension method / override the HasKeys() ?. Read the querystring in that method and split it with & and then again with = on each items of the first split result. Then return Yes or No

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this so I don't know if it works, but you could try checking against these counts:

```
int keys = Request.QueryString.Keys.Count;
int args = Request.QueryString.Count;

if (keys != args) ...
```

Comment: Great idea! but it doesn't work :( Just tested a sec ago. Request.QueryString.Keys.Count always == Request.QueryString.Count